# Why labels on chart are not shown when drawn after axes

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm making a simple line chart with in-chart labels using d3.js.

When I draw the axes before the labels, the latter do not get added to the svg element, but they do if I draw them first:

[image: Charts obtained when alternating drawing of axes and labels.]

In the second chart, the labels are not just hidden. They are not being appended to the DOM at all.

[Here's the bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/rbonvall/8565121). The only difference between both scripts is that `before.js` writes labels before axes, while `after.js` does it afterwards.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line when adding the labels:

```
svg.selectAll('text')
```

If you have drawn the axes at this point. There will be `text` elements and the selection above will not be empty. Calling `.data()` on it causes D3 to match data elements to DOM elements in the selection. In this case, everything is matched and therefore the `.enter()` selection is empty and no new labels are added.

It works if you run this code first because there are no `text` elements, the selection is empty and no data is matched. To prevent this, you can for example identify the label `text` elements explicitly with a class:

```
svg.selectAll('text.label')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr("class", "label")
        .text(Math.floor)
        .attr('class', 'data-label')
        .attr('x', function (d, i) { return x(i); })
        .attr('y', function (d, i) { return y(d + 1); });
```

With this code, it doesn't matter whether you run it before or after adding the axes.